# why does ifstream read fail for int with 0x80000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ifstream

In a simple console application I am trying to read a file containing a hex value on each line.

It works for the first few, but after 4 or 5 it starts outputting cdcdcdcd.

Any idea why this is? Is there a limit on using read in this basic manner?

The first byte of the file is its size.

```
std::ifstream read("file.bin");

int* data;
try
{
    data = new int [11398];
}
    catch (int e)
{
    std::cout << "Error - dynamic array not created. Code: [" << e << "]\n"; 
}

int size = 0;
read>>std::hex>>size;
std::cout<<std::hex<<size<<std::endl;

for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    read>>std::hex>>data[i];
    std::cout<<std::hex<<data[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

The values I get returned are:

```
576 (size)    
1000323    
2000000    
1000005    
cdcdcdcd
cdcdcdcd    
cdcdcdcd    
...
```

The first value that is meant to be output in cdcdcdcd's place is 80000000.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? You're probably going past the end of the array.

Comment: edited, the array ends up being 11398

Comment: @Tom Also check the state of your input stream: `if(!read>>std::hex>>data[i]) {break;}`

Comment: You're right, it does come up with a read error. Though is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: _'Though is there anything I can do about that?'_ Yes, check the input at the point of failure, if it fit's what you're trying to read. I think changing `int* data;` to `unsigned int* data;` or `long* data;` (and the allocation accordingly of course), should solve your problem.

Comment: unsigned int* seems to work. It wasn't quite what I was intending, as I wanted it to be signed, but I may just deal with it at a later stage. As in, interpret the value as signed when I need to use it. So long as it is saved into an array I am good. I figure it did not like using a value which started with 8 (80000000) rather than 0 or 1.

Comment: @Tom And what about `long*` or `long long*`, these are signed types. Even better, if you want to be sure about which size finally should fit you may use the types defined in [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: Retracted my close vote and voted to reopen (which I should have done after the OP's first  edit). The close hit me just when I was trying to write an appropriate answer about this not too unclear question.

Comment: `80000000` is not representable in an `int`, so the `>>` operator is failing. You aren't checking for failure, so you are printing uninitialized garbage.

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1198/c/c1198.aspx) from the Microsoft Systems Journal. From the Q&A, "0xCDCDCDCD is a debugging value that comes from the bowels of the C runtime library. When you allocate a block of memory in a debug build, it's initialized to this spurious value in the hope of catching bugs. 0xCDCDCDCD is non-NULL and is never a valid memory pointer."

Answer (score 3):

You are overflowing an int.

If you change to unsigned int. You will be able to fill to 0xFFFFFFFF

You can check with:

```
std::cout << "Range of integer: " 
          << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() 
          << "  <Value> " 
          << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() 
          << "\n";


std::cout << "Range of integer: " 
          << std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() 
          << "  <Value> " 
          << std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min() 
          << "\n";
```

Note: There is no negative hex values (it is designed as a compact representation for a bit representation).

You should really check that the read worked:

```
 if (read>>std::hex>>data[i])
 {
     // read worked
 }
 else
 {
     // read failed.
 }
```

Comment: 0x80000000, is not an overflow, surely? 
In binary it is 10000... and overflow would be 0xFFFFFFFF + 1

Comment: Why not. That's 32 bits. And would set the top bit (which makes it negative thus an overflow for a signed value). For unsigned int it should work. The largest value for a 32 bit signed value is: 0x7FFFFFFF

Comment: Negative == overflow? It is proving difficult to simply change to an unsigned value. However, I am tired.

Comment: @Tom read into an unsigned, and if it's greater than `INT_MAX` then convert to signed. (If you don't care about esoteric implementations then you can just do a simple assignment to the signed int)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like your read fails.

Note that on a 32-bit `int` system, `0x80000000` is out of range for `int`. The range of valid values is probably -0x80000000 through to 0x7FFFFFFF.

It's important not to mix up *values* with *representations*.  "0x80000000" , when read via `std::hex`, means the positive integer which is written as 80000000 in base 16.   It's neither here nor there that a particular negative integer may be stored internally in a signed `int` in 2's complement with the same binary representation as a positive value of type `unsigned int` has when the positive integer 80000000 is stored in it.

Consider reading into `unsigned int` if you intend to use this technique. Also, it is *essential* that you check the read operation for success or failure.  If a stream extraction fails then the stream is put into an error state, where all subsequent reads fail until you call `.clear()` on the stream.

NB. `std::hex` (and all other modifiers actually) are "sticky": once you set it, it stays set until you actually specify `std::dec` to restore the default.